# Retrieving sd-card details of BlackBerry Device Using PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, blackberry, sd-card

I am using PhoneGap to develop an app for BlackBerry.
How do I get details of the sd-card, such as available and used space, on a BlackBerry device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so that so its possible using PhoneGap.You can retrieve other information of mobile devices using PhoneGap Device API.

Here is one example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Properties Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-x.x.x.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var element = document.getElementById('deviceProperties');

        element.innerHTML = 'Device Name: '     + device.name     + '<br />' + 
                            'Device Cordova: '  + device.cordova + '<br />' + 
                            'Device Platform: ' + device.platform + '<br />' + 
                            'Device UUID: '     + device.uuid     + '<br />' + 
                            'Device Model: '    + device.model     + '<br />' + 
                            'Device Version: '  + device.version  + '<br />';
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p id="deviceProperties">Loading device properties...</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any native method through witch I can get my blackberry device's sd-card details..??

Comment: @shreyashsamani-No.If you are developing an application using PhoneGap then you have to use PhoneGap APIs to access features of the Mobile devices.There is no such a method that is providing the details of the sd card particularly in PhoneGap.